# Bash argument parser with support for concatenated flags and '=' or ' ' between arguments and values

Tags: parsing, bash

This is my best attempt so far at a bash script argument parser written without GNU `getopt` or bash `getopts`

the first two functions, `usage` and `err` can be more or less ignored, but I plan on adding the ability to specify an exit code when calling `err`.

Now for the first section of code in the `main` function:

```
shopt -s extglob
args=()
for (( i = 1; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
  arg="${!i}"
  case "${arg}" in
    -[[:alpha:]?]+([[:alpha:]?]))
      for (( j = 1; j < "${#arg}"; j++ )); do
        args+=("-${arg:j:1}")
      done ;;
    -[[:alpha:]]=*|--*=*)
      args+=("${arg%%=*}")
      args+=("${arg#*=}") ;;
    *)
      args+=("${arg}") ;;
  esac
done
set -- "${args[@]}"
shopt -u extglob
```

This section de-concatenates flags and separates flags joined to their values with an `=`.
as an example, `./script -xYz --test=value` would pop out as `./script -x -Y -z --test value`. Most of this could likely have been combined with the second part, but I think there's at least a little value in being able to access/save the intermediate form, and it made debugging easier. Single letter flags with `=` can also be processed, but as I understand it, this isn't an extremely common thing to see anyway. Flags that are already in the correct format, flags that could not be reformatted due to user error (`./script -xYz=value`, for instance), and positional parameters would both be passed to the second part without any modification. This hasn't caused any issues yet, but I am considering trying to further differentiate between good/bad input. at the very end, the reformatted args are `set` for later use.

Part two of the `main` function:

```
  args=()
  for (( i = 1; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
    arg="${!i}"
    case "${arg}" in
      --)
        break ;;
      -*)
        case "${arg}" in
          -h|--help|-\?)
            usage ;;
          -x|-Y|-z) ;;
          -t|--type)
            arg2="${!i+1}"
            if [[ -n "${arg2}" ]] && [[ "${arg2:0:1}" != "-" ]]; then
              type="${arg2}"
              (( i++ ))
            else
              err "Invalid option: ${arg} requires an argument"
            fi ;;
          -*)
            err "Invalid option: ${arg}" ;;
        esac ;;
      *)
        args+=("${arg}")
    esac
  done
  set -- "${args[@]}"
```

This is where flags and their values actually get processed. Flags (and their arguments, if applicable) are checked one at a time, but only unused positional parameters are put back in the array to be set once again. For example `./script -x -Y -z --test value hello world` would pop out as `./script hello world`

I did what I could to prevent any special cases slipping through, and to account for as many common formats as possible, but I couldn't find a list of either, so I'd really appreciate advice on both of those issues.

I also have very little experience writing bash scripts, so general bash scripting advice would also be greatly appreciated.

Full code:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
  echo "help me"
  exit 0
}

err() {
  echo "$*" >&2
  exit 1
}

shopt -s extglob

main() {
  shopt -s extglob
  args=()
  for (( i = 1; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
    arg="${!i}"
    case "${arg}" in
      -[[:alpha:]?]+([[:alpha:]?]))
        for (( j = 1; j < "${#arg}"; j++ )); do
          args+=("-${arg:j:1}")
        done ;;
      -[[:alpha:]]=*|--*=*)
        args+=("${arg%%=*}")
        args+=("${arg#*=}") ;;
      *)
        args+=("${arg}") ;;
    esac
  done
  set -- "${args[@]}"
  shopt -u extglob

  echo "$0 $@"

  args=()
  for (( i = 1; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
    arg="${!i}"
    case "${arg}" in
      --)
        break ;;
      -*)
        case "${arg}" in
          -h|--help|-\?)
            usage ;;
          -x|-Y|-z) ;;
          -t|--type)
            arg2="${!i+1}"
            if [[ -n "${arg2}" ]] && [[ "${arg2:0:1}" != "-" ]]; then
              type="${arg2}"
              (( i++ ))
            else
              err "Invalid option: ${arg} requires an argument"
            fi ;;
          -*)
            err "Invalid option: ${arg}" ;;
        esac ;;
      *)
        args+=("${arg}")
    esac
  done
  set -- "${args[@]}"

  echo "$0 ${@:-No positional parameters set}"
  echo "test: ${test:-Test not set}"
}
shopt -u extglob

main "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty nicely written Bash.

I see the parsing happens in two passes:

- Convert the argument list to some sort of canonical form
- Validate the argument list

This is easy to understand and I think it makes sense.

#### Handling arguments after `--`

As written, the program ignores all further arguments after `--`.

The common practice is to take all arguments after `--` verbatim, without further parsing.
For example this behavior makes it possible to use the `rm` command to delete a file named `-f` if you ever need it. You would do that with `rm -- -f` instead of `rm -f` (which usually does nothing).

#### Keeping things "simple"

I'm not a fan of advanced features of Bash. I think they are pushing the limits of the language, and a common source of bugs, and code that's difficult to understand.

Look at what `extglob` forces you to do:

- `shopt -s extglob` before the declaration of `main` and cleaning up with `shopt -u extglob` after it, so that `main` can be parsed
- Then inside `main`, again `shopt -s extglob` before you need it, and cleaning up with `shopt -u extglob` when you no longer need it

I find this double activation / deactivation dirty.

If you gotta use it, you gotta use it. If I have a chance to do without it, I would. And here I see an opportunity. By reorganizing the conditions, you could achieve something similar:

```
args=()
for (( i = 1; i <= $#; i++ )); do
  arg="${!i}"
  case "${arg}" in
    -[[:alpha:]]=*|--*=*)
      args+=("${arg%%=*}")
      args+=("${arg#*=}") ;;
    --)
      for (( j = i; j <= $#; j++ )); do
        args+=("${!j}")
      done
      break ;;
    --*)
      args+=("${arg}") ;;
    -*)
      for (( j = 1; j < "${#arg}"; j++ )); do
        args+=("-${arg:j:1}")
      done ;;
    *)
      args+=("${arg}") ;;
  esac
done
set -- "${args[@]}"
```

The difference from your original is that `-[[:alpha:]?]+([[:alpha:]?])` is replaced with simply `-*`. To put it simply, I think the practical implication is that an argument like `-c9` would be converted to `-c -9` instead of keeping it as `-c9`.

I don't know if this would be acceptable to you. If yes, then you could get rid of all the `shopt`, and I think that would be a good thing.

#### shellcheck

As you are new to Bash, it's probably good to point out [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) (also available as a command line tool), a nice tool to check Bash code against common mistakes and bad practices.
It finds just a minor issue about `echo "$0 $@"`, where the recommended usage would be `echo "$0 $*"`.

Comment: so instead of just ending the parse loop, everything after `--` should be just be passed without modification to be used as a positional parameter? That makes sense, and explains why `set --` behaves the way it does. That should also let me remove the nested case in part 2. are there any other special cases (like `--`) I may have missed?